# Angular: Handling of nested router-outlets and submodules

Tags: angular, angular-module, router-outlet

I'm doing some experiments with Angular on how to define 'fully contained' modules (meaning that each module should have not only its own components definitions, but their routes as well, and, if necessary, guards to protect each of its routes), but I'm facing some problems with nested routes and the respective `router-outlets`.

The main purpose of this experiment is to have different layouts whether the user is authenticated or not:

- if it's not authenticated, a simple page with a login form will be shown (there's also a change to do a 'Forgot your password?' type of form, on another route)
- if it's authenticated, the layout (I've called `private-layout`) should always have a navbar and a `router-outlet` there, where the pages accessible when authenticated should be displayed.

The problem is that, for some reason, the `private-layout` is not being injected and its nested routes are injected directly on main `router-outlet`.

I have a Stackblitz that can better illustrate the scenario: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bsqgfl

As you can see, when the app starts, it goes directly into the AuthModule (since it matches the empty route), where you can see the 'login' component injected into the Auth's `router-outlet`. You can even try switching from 'login' to 'forgot-pw' and the 'forgot password' nested content will inject as expected.
But, if you try changing the URL to 'test', instead of seeing a navbar and the test component injected as well, the navbar is not showing at all, because the test component was injected directly on the main `router-outlet`.

I'm fairly sure this is related to how I'm defining the routes, but I'd like for them to keep as close to its module as possible, but I can't figure how to handle this. I've come across a few answers here, but all of them had all of the possible app routes defined in a single place, but I want mine to spread across each respective module.